# Expand tag filter with additional options

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, filtering

Sometimes I want to search questions which are marked let's say with `c#` tag and either `.net` or `.net-core` and are not marked with `entity-framework`. But, currently it is not possible. It would be great to support complex tag query builder which has such options:

1. OR - requires that at least of multiple tags is applied.
2. Ignore - Ignore questions which is marked with specified tag.

In overall, as a user I will be happy to select questions in a way something like this:

```
 [c#] and ([.net], [.net-core]) and ![entity-framework]
```

In such case I want to select questions which are marked with `c#` tag, plus either [.net] or [.net-core] and are not marked with [entity-framework].

Comment: doable with SEDE today: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1146230

Comment: @rene Thanks for the query. I really appreciate it. But, it would be greay if that was integrated to the website as a a feature, because in webste we can automatically see whether new question is asked matches to the filter or not. I normally open a special tab in the browser abd in case of new question tab text is also refreshed and includes the count of the newest questions.

Answer (score 7):

This query seems to work:

- [`[c#] ( [.net] or [.net-core] ) -[entity-framework]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%28+%5B.net%5D+or+%5B.net-core%5D+%29+-%5Bentity-framework%5D)
- [`is:question [c#] ( [.net] or [.net-core] ) -[entity-framework]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bc%23%5D+%28+%5B.net%5D+or+%5B.net-core%5D+%29+-%5Bentity-framework%5D)

However, it doesn't seem to be usable in filters. Furthermore, there're multiple problems with this query:

1. Priority of `and` and `or` is reversed, compared to Google, which makes parens necessary too often. I guess this can't be fixed because of backward compatibility.
2. Parens require spaces around them. It's completely counter-intuitive and isn't mentioned in the documentation. The same query without spaces (`[c#] ([.net] or [.net-core]) -[entity-framework]`) is broken.
3. If you try entering this query into filters, the filters box disappears momentarily (bug?). Applying it removes parens and so breaks the query.

I find it weird that search in filters involves reinventing wheels (square wheels really, considering how good they work).